# How to detail vertical brick to siding transition

Tags: exterior, brick, vinyl-siding

My old East Coast row home has a wood framed addition that was built in to the existing extended party wall.  Where the rear face, which is vinyl sided, joins the perpendicular brick wall, there is a gap that I want to close.  How should this be flashed/otherwise detailed? The J-channel is proud of the brick.

The close up shows the current transition. There's a piece of metal flashing under the J-channel and folding back behind the brick.

[image]

[image]

[image: Rear House Detail of brick meeting vinyl]

Comment: Is water leaking in?

Comment: No water, just birds and cold air so far

Comment: This is a great overview pic. Would you get a closer pic of the brick/whatever/J-channel joint and [edit] that into your question, please. It's hard to tell what's actually going on there. What kind of material is between the brick & J-channel?

Comment: @FreeMan, from right to left it's J-channel, turned back metal flashing, and then brick

Comment: At this point, mortar, unless you're going to redo the siding. Or Volcom caulk if you're lazy or it's a contract and not getting paid by the hour to tuck point, and neither you nor the costumer GAF. Should be mortared *and then* Volcom'ed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would want a Z-flashing capping the end of the brick as an aesthetically clean (professional) and reliable solution. You need to flash to a point where you either have natural gravity drainage or you can caulk to a straight, flat surface, and you want to cover the irregular brick edge to conceal it. The flashing could be color-matched with the brick to reduce visual impact.

I'm not sure whether you could install this without uninstalling the vinyl (not a huge job), but here's what I would do if I was starting from scratch.

```
PLAN (TOP) VIEW


  |       | _________ 
  | brick |||‾‾‾‾‾‾
 ||_______|||__ <-- J-channel
  ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
      ^-- custom Z-flashing with terminal hem
```

If you didn't want a complete cap on the brick you could stop it short of the left-hand corner and use a foam gasket or caulk to close things up.

Comment: A very reasonable approach. I'd think that the flashing could be pushed behind the J-channel until it hits the nails holding the channel in place. I don't think it would need a Z profile, though, just an angle (based on looking at OP's pics). I'd definitely wrap around the corner of the brick (after tuck pointing). I'd probably put a layer of caulk/construction adhesive on the face & around the corner to hold the metal in place.

Comment: A simple angle leaves the joint between it and the J-channel as an avenue for water ingress, no?

Comment: Potentially, yes. No more so, I'd think, than the current piece of metal stuck behind the J-channel. In order to prevent water ingress behind the J-channel, I'd put a bead of caulk along there. But, that's me and I'm no expert. (I just play one on the internet.)

Comment: I've come to categorically distrust caulk as an effective long-term solution for almost anything. It's just about guaranteed to let you down. That's why I suggest a full-width flashing.

Answer (score 1):

Yeesh! I'm far from an expert, but I'd suggest that the proper solution would be to:

- Fold the flashing *out* (to get it out of the way)

  - It might be possible/reasonable/the best bet to simply cut off the flashing as best as possible behind the J-channel since it appears that it was put in place to cover the gap and the gap will be closed up by the next steps.
- Do a proper tuck pointing of the existing bricks
- Run the mortar to the right to fill in the gaps to whatever is behind the siding.

  - Note that this might take some proper waterproofing of the material behind the siding (wood, I'd presume). Mortar will wick moisture and bring it to the structure, speeding rot, if it's not properly water proofed.

Tuck pointing isn't easy - I've done just a little bit and it's a lot more work than you'd think! However, it can certainly be DIY'd. It might be worth getting a mason to at least look at this and give an estimate to

1. Ensure this would be the proper approach
2. Find out what the expense would be to have a pro do it. Especially if it's going to take some remediation of the wall behind the siding.